# HTML DOM event for Iframe with 204 response

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dom-events

I would like to know what iframe DOM events are triggered when an iframe gets loaded with a source that replies 204, i know it has no content, but at least an event i can handle that in.

Comment: are you pointing to `load` event?

Comment: i dont think load is called when the response is 204, or atleast not in all browsers? am i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As there is no content loaded it won't be triggering any `events` or we can say there won't be any `states` on which we can trigger. Still, if you want to catch **No Content** cases you can try it something like this:

```
var iframeLoaded = false;

$('iframe').on('load', function(){ 
  iframeLoaded =  true
});

if(iframeLoaded){
  console.log('loaded')
}else{
  console.log('notloaded')
}
```

if the frame gets loaded this will trigger `load` events and set the variable `iframeLoaded` as **true**.